# Obsolete attribute NDepend

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, cql, ndepend

Does anyone know a simple way to get the attribute of an obsolete marked methods with NDepend?

`Obsolete["This is outdated"] //TODO, I want the string!!`

So any ideas on how to get the string using NDepend?

Comment: I don't think you've understood my queston, with NDepend we do a query for the code and it is a plugin for Visual studio. Reflection in Csharp code works fine, but my question is specifically how to do it with CQLinq which is what I need to do using NDepend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NDepend you can get the attribute type,the methods/types/assemblies... tagged with the attribute, but you cannot get the string in the attribute. Much better than reflection, we'd advise using the framework [Mono.Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil) for that.